# C libcurl smaller than expected response size

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use libcurl to download the content of a webpage however the responses I get back are much smaller than expected - the documentation says that the maximum size is 16K but the responses I'm getting are much much smaller than that.

For example, requesting the [en Wikipedia page "Hello"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello) returns a size of 1239 bytes when the page is 71915 bytes in gedit. Requesting [a page from the haveibeenpwned API](https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/ABCDE) returns a size of 554, not the actual size which is 19942 bytes.

```
int callback(char* resultPtr, size_t ignore, size_t resultSize) { // resultPtr points to the start of the response, ignore is always 1, resultSize varies
    printf("Response size is %i", resultSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++) { printf("%c", *(resultPtr+i));} // credit @BartFriederichs
    return 0;
}

int doCurl(char* paramsPtr) {
    char url[43]; // Add space for /0
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init(); // Initialise cURL
    strcpy(url, "https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/"); // Testing URL
    strcat(url, &*paramsPtr); // Always 5 characters
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url); // cURL URL set to URL specified above
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 120000L); // Tried to set this to make the output longer
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

The point of this code is to get the response from HIBP's Pwned Passwords API and compare a string given by the user to the results from the webpage. The search succeed for any strings within the first 554 bytes (first chunk of data output by cURL) but fail after that.

Comment: What is in the result? Is the actual data chopped off, or are you actually getting something different (e.g. headers).

Comment: You declared `url[]` as an array of 35 chars. After copying `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/` and your 5-character string into this array, you've used up all of these 35 characters. There is no room left for the `'\0'` string terminator. What you're probably seeing are 404 error pages.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I've just looked, running `for(int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++) { printf("%c", &*resultPtr); }` outputs this: https://imgur.com/a/GJwHnqD. I think I may have misunderstood the writefunction, it looks like it's calling it multiple times?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage a Wikipedia 404 is longer than 1239 bytes.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Good point - I have changed this however the problem still exists.

Comment: That `for` loop doesn't work. You should `printf("%c", *(resultPtr+i));`

Comment: @BartFriederichs, you're right - sorry. I've updated this and the output is working now. So I guess what I need to do is try and combine all of the separate outputs from cURL in to one and then search it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html). It says:

> The callback function will be passed as much data as possible in all invokes, but you must not make any assumptions. It may be one byte, it may be thousands.

It doesn't say so explicitly, but this function might be called more than once. You can use the `userdata` pointer (which you haven't used) to keep track of your previous data. I advise you also take a look at the [example code](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html):

```
struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

  char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    /* out of memory! */ 
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }

  mem->memory = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

  return realsize;
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't say so explicitly" ... thanks, I took this feedback and have updated the man page to make this fact more explicit!